# How to automatically get an available port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working with docker containers for some projects and to save time i clone the docker composer file for my other projects.

The problem I have is that the ports for my mysql_database and apache_service are fixed values.

Example:

```yaml
version: "3.2"

services:
  apache_service:
    build:
      context: './docker/apache/'
    links:
      - mysql_service:mysql_service
    depends_on:
      - mysql_service
    ports:
      - "8080:80" # "random_port:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/

  mysql_service:
    build:
      context    : ./
      dockerfile : ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    command: [
      '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
      '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password',
    ]
    restart:
      always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./docker/mysql/logs:/var/log/mysql
    ports:
      - "4306:3306" # "random_port:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    container_name:
      mysql_service
```

When i copy the docker-composer file and write `docker-composer up` i alwayas have to change the ports previously...

How i could automatily get an avaliable port for this services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `0` as the host port: this way you will get the first available (random) port from the operating system; to later get the actual used port you can use the `docker port <container>` command.

Comment: Omitting the host port and just specifying `ports: ['80']` will have the same effect.  There is a [`docker-compose port`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/port/) helper that avoids needing to know (or set) the generated Docker container name.